# Response Data from Django API not Fetching correctly, got an empty array #React,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I have the following data in the API in the backend (does this mean that I have backend well settled?):

[image]

And I'd like to display them in the frontend something like this:

[image]

Instead, I got the following empty page:

[image]

The structure of the folder is:

[image]

And the code of api.js file is the following:

```js
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

function request(path,{ data = null, token = null, method = "GET"}) {
    return fetch(path, {
        method,
        headers: {
            Authorization: token ? `Token ${token}` : "",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: method !== "GET" && method !== "DELETE" ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        // If it is success
        if(response.ok) {
            if (method === "DELETE") {
                // if delete, nothing return
                return true;
            }
            return response.json();
        }
        //Otherwise, if there are errors
        return response
            .json()
            .then((json)=>{
                // Handle Json Error, response by the server
                if (response.status === 400) {
                    const errors = Object.keys(json).map(
                        (k) => `${(json[k].join(" "))}`
                    );
                    throw new Error(errors.join(" "));
                } 
                throw new Error(JSON.stringify(json));
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                if (e.name === "SyntaxError") {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                throw new Error(e);
            })
    })
    .catch((e) =>{
        //Handle all errors 
        toast(e.message,{type: "error"})
    })
}


export function fetchPlaces({token}) {
    return request("/api/places/",
    {
        token
    });
}
```

And the code in Places.js is :

```
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { fetchPlaces } from '../apis';
import AuthContext from '../contexts/AuthContext';

import MainLayout from '../layouts/MainLayout';


const Place = styled.div`
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    :hover {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    >div {
        background-size: cover;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    > p {
        margin-top: 5px
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
`;

const Places = () => {
    const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

    const onFetchPlaces = async () => {
        const json = await fetchPlaces(auth.token);
        console.log(auth.token);
        if (json) {
            setPlaces(json);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        onFetchPlaces();
    }, []);

    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <h3>My Places</h3>
            <Row>
                {places.map((place) => (
                    <Col key={place.id} lg={4}>
                        <Place>
                            <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${place.image})`}}></div>
                            <p>{place.name}</p>
                        </Place>
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </MainLayout>
    )
};

export default Places;
```

I did some debugging and the findings are the followings:

- `Auth.token` is the same as the one in the admin/users token
- places is an empty array, this means that it failed fetching the data from API.

Even though I discovered that the problem comes from the fetching, I cannot detect where is wrong in the code, does anyone has any clue?